# Invoking a method on multiple cached DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I always trying to cache DOM selection when using jQuery to manipulate DOM. And I always thought if is it possible to shorthand such method calling:

```
var $cached_1 = $('#elem1'),
    $cached_2 = $('#elem2');

//For example i need toggle both I write like : 
$cached_1.toggle();
$cached_2.toggle();
```

Without the cache it is easy:

```
$('#elem1, #elem2').toggle();
```

But what about cached selections? Is there a similar way to call a method for few separate selections stored in variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a similar method to do that,

```
var elems = $('#elem1').add('#elem2');
elems.toggle();
```

You have to use [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) to achieve what you want.

Comment: What's the difference with `"#elem1, #elem2"`?

Comment: Think you wanted `$cached_1.add($cached_2)`. otherwise it doesn't answer question

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález He asked an alternate way for using multiple selector.  And to:OP You could also cache elements returned from a multiple selector.

Comment: Mine was a real question, I wanted to ensure I wasn't missing something. If you end up with a jQuery element that has the same node collection, you are just making the code harder to understand for no benefit. This looks like one of those "how do I drive a nail without a hammer" type of questions.

Answer (score 1):

If those will always be used as a collection, store the collection.

```
var $els = $('#elem1, #elem2');
$els.toggle();
```

Or if you want to combine previously cached variables:

```
$cached_1.add($cached_2).toggle();
```

Comment: Thats the answer too. But if i use 2 of them separately, and other I store as a collection. Isn't it bad to have so many cached selectors?

Comment: OK..updated with the way you really want to use `add()` to avoid DOM search again as per other answer